# Building debugger C# on Extjs4 and Asp.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, c#-4.0, extjs4

I'm building an interface Extjs4, which allows writing code c #. I can generate an executable file, but I would allow functions such as step over, step in. The application is built on Asp.NET MVC2 using c#.

Anyone have an idea?

I tried to work with mindbg: http://mindbg.codeplex.com/, but do not know how to integrate it.

My idea is to show the variable and value, as does the debugger VisualStudio.Net

Any advice?

thanks